# connect to a remote host in perl and run ssh commands as a root user

Tags: shell, perl, filebeat, cpan

I am trying to connect to a remote host as a user. Now i want to run a few commands that need sudo access. The commands are:

```bash
export http_proxy=http://xxxx.xx.xx.com:8080
export https_proxy=http://xxxx-xxxx.xx.xx.com:8080
sudo /etc/init.d/filebeat restart
sudo tail -f /var/log/filebeat/filebeat
```

I tried executing this using

```perl
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("$username\@$Hostname", password => $pass);
my @cmdF = "/etc/init.d/filebeat restart";
print "Restarting filebeat for $webHosts[$i]";
my @cmdF = "/etc/init.d/filebeat restart";
my $outputF = $ssh->capture({stdin_data=>"$pass\n"}, 'sudo', '-Sk', '-p', '', '-', @cmdF);
print "\nCurrent Filebeat Status : $outputF\n\n";
```

I took just one command at the moment but ended up getting this error:

```
sudo: /etc/init.d/filebeat restart: command not found
```

Please help me with the same for all commands..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `my @cmdF = ("/etc/init.d/filebeat" "restart")` instead, i.e. separat command and command arguments in different list entries. Otherwise sudo will look a file named `/etc/init.d/filebeat restart` to execute - which does not exist

Comment: What is `$ssh`?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo /etc/init.d/filebeat restart` consists of three arguments (including the command):

1. `sudo`
2. `/etc/init.d/filebeat`
3. `restart`

You execute these instead:

1. `sudo`
2. `-Sk`
3. `-p`
4. Empty string
5. `-`
6. `/etc/init.d/filebeat restart`

Most relevant is that you combined two arguments into one, producing garbage.

What you need:

```perl
my $commands = <<'.';
export http_proxy=http://xxxx.xx.xx.com:8080
export https_proxy=http://xxxx-xxxx.xx.xx.com:8080
sudo /etc/init.d/filebeat restart
sudo tail -f /var/log/filebeat/filebeat
.

$ssh->capture( 'sh', '-c', $commands );
```

Comment: How should I pass the password in this case then?

Comment: Are you saying you want to execute different commands than the ones you said you wanted to execute? Feel free to fix your question if that's the case.

Comment: I wish to run these commands as a root user on a remote host for which I was passing an argument called $pass.

Comment: I copied the commands you posted exactly.commands you posted exactly. There's no password argument. If you want to run sh itself as root, feel free to use the approach you were using.